# JQuery file upload, where does it go?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have been following [This tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/) on using the JQuery file upload plugin. everything looks fine and when I select a file to upload the browser there are no errors but the file doesn't seem to upload. I could be wrong but I assumed the file would be in the `uploads` folder in the project directory(eclipse). Here is the code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Mini Ajax File Upload Form</title>

        <!-- Google web fonts -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel='stylesheet' />

        <!-- The main CSS file -->
        <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="drop">
                Drop Here

                <a>Browse</a>
                <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
            </div>

            <ul>
                <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
            </ul>

        </form>

        <!-- JavaScript Includes -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>

        <!-- jQuery File Upload Dependencies -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

        <!-- Our main JS file -->
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$(function(){

    var ul = $('#upload ul');

    $('#drop a').click(function(){
        // Simulate a click on the file input button
        // to show the file browser dialog
        $(this).parent().find('input').click();
    });

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
    $('#upload').fileupload({

        // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
        dropZone: $('#drop'),

        // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
        // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
        add: function (e, data) {

            var tpl = $('<li class="working"><input type="text" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48"'+
                ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p><span></span></li>');

            // Append the file name and file size
            tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name)
                         .append('<i>' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');

            // Add the HTML to the UL element
            data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

            // Initialize the knob plugin
            tpl.find('input').knob();

            // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
            tpl.find('span').click(function(){

                if(tpl.hasClass('working')){
                    jqXHR.abort();
                }

                tpl.fadeOut(function(){
                    tpl.remove();
                });

            });

            // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
            var jqXHR = data.submit();
        },

        progress: function(e, data){

            // Calculate the completion percentage of the upload
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

            // Update the hidden input field and trigger a change
            // so that the jQuery knob plugin knows to update the dial
            data.context.find('input').val(progress).change();

            if(progress == 100){
                data.context.removeClass('working');
            }
        },

        fail:function(e, data){
            // Something has gone wrong!
            data.context.addClass('error');
        }

    });


    // Prevent the default action when a file is dropped on the window
    $(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Helper function that formats the file sizes
    function formatFileSize(bytes) {
        if (typeof bytes !== 'number') {
            return '';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
        }

        return (bytes / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' KB';
    }

});
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php

// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip');

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    }
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
```

All the other required js files are also present. When i run it on tomcat, my output looks like this:

[image: Browser view/console output/project structure]

I refreshed the project as well so that's not it. Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not running PHP on the server so the upload isn't saved anywhere.

You need to install PHP on the server, move to a server that has PHP installed or change to another language.

It looks like you're using Windows. You could try using [WAMP-server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

Comment: How can you tell the servers not got PHP installed ?

Comment: Because the PHP source code is sent to firefox/firebug. If PHP was installed, the PHP script would've executed instead. Now the web server just thinks it's plain text and sends it as it is to the browser.